# Using Relationship in Jamie Rumbelow MY_model

Tags: php, codeigniter, relationship, has-many, belongs-to

I am using MY_model as is [Codeigniter-base-model](https://github.com/jamierumbelow/codeigniter-base-model). I am unable to get the basic relationship working. I searched a lot but could find solution.

---

To start with I have 2 classes `item_model.php` & `user_model.php` both extend MY_Model.

In `item_model` class I have defined

```
public $belongs_to = array( 'user' => array( 'model' => 'user_model') );
```

and in the `user_model`

```
public $has_many = array( 'items' => array( 'model' => 'item_model') );
```

Now, in the controller when I call

```
$item_details = $this->item_model->with('user')->find_by_id($item_id);
```

I am getting the correct data for `$item_details` but I am unable to get information from the 'user' relationship.  `$item_details->user_id->username;`.

I am getting following error

> Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Table are standard

```
users table has id, username, ...
item table has id, user_id, title...

user_id is is setUp as FK to users.id.
```

Please help.

Comment: What's the `find_by_id` method?

Comment: Thanks @JamieRumbelow for your response. I had written my own function in MY_model, could you please give me clarity of how this should work?

Comment: Well, are you using the built in finder methods to grab the data? If you're not, then the observers aren't being called, so the relationships aren't being selected appropriately. I'll need to see some code to help you, I'm afraid.

Comment: P.S. don't edit MY_Model directly, create a Base_Model class or something that extends from MY_Model. If you want to update MY_Model in the future it'll be a pain.

Comment: Got it, I've done the same. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you check source code of relate() method, you will found this piece of the code:

```
if (is_string($value))
        {
            $relationship = $value;
            $options = array( 'primary_key' => $value . '_id', 'model' => $value . '_model' );
        }
        else
        {
            $relationship = $key;
            $options = $value;
        }
```

I check the source code, if you use a array to define the model, you need to define 'primary_key' as well, this is not in document.

'primary_key' means which foreign key of this table to link my primary_key.

```
public $belongs_to = array( 'user' => array( 'model' => 'user_model','primary_key'=>'user_id') );
```

will be more right.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't `$item_details->user_id->username;` be `$item_details->user->username;`?

Also is your user table called `user` or `users`? You're telling it here to call it `user`:

```
public $belongs_to = array( 'user' => array( 'model' => 'user_model') );
```

Comment: Yes the table name is `users`. I had tried `$item_details->user->username;` didn't work this gives two errors.                         `Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined property: stdClass::$user
Line Number: 5
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Trying to get property of non-object
`

Comment: Does this answer your question? If so, can you mark it as such?